# HTTPS on Login page, but no lock symbol in browser using IIS URL Rewrite Module

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, web-config

I have an ASP.NET site that's now using the IIS URL Rewrite Module so that I can specify my rules in the web.config.  I have it so that only the Login page will always be HTTPS and all other pages will always be HTTP.  This works great, except for the fact that going to the site in any browser doesn't show the lock icon when using this method (as opposed to making the whole site HTTPS and removing the web.config rewrite rules...the lock shows then).

With the rules on, Edge asks me to allow blocked content.  Chrome tells me "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources", and when allowing it puts a red strike through the https in the URL bar.

How can I get the Login page to always be HTTPS and the other pages to all be HTTP always, while also showing the lock symbol and allowing all content on the login page when using the IIS Rewrite Module?  I'm assuming that maybe the images or JS files or something that are using on the Login page (and other pages) aren't delivered over HTTPS maybe?  The rewrite rules are:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for Login page only" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(Login.aspx)" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTPS to HTTP for non Login pages" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{R:1}" pattern="(login.aspx)" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: The page in question is: https://test.academicanalytics.com/Login.aspx

Comment: this is nothing wrong with the rule; it is something referred in the Login.aspx that is not secure; in order to show https, every reference on the page should be secure

Comment: try prefixing your references to images/css/scripts with //test.academicanalytics.com/; //generally refers to whatever protocol you are on; it will take automatically

Comment: you can check why it is not showing at https://www.whynopadlock.com/

Comment: Is there a way I could write a rule to do this?  I ask because we want to try and do this across multiple sites using the web.config settings rather than going through to all the pages. This looks like an answer, but through a 500 error: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/09/25/ASPNET-Fix-for-HTTPS-SSL-Insecure-Mixed-Content-Warning.aspx

Comment: one option is to add your css / javascript / images that you are referring in Login.aspx to the rule that redirects to https; basically you are redirecting Login.aspx to https but not the referenced links

Comment: @user2169261 adding the css, js, and images to the rule sounds great.  Any idea on how to do this?  I just learned about IIS Rewrite Module yesterday, so this is new to me. ;)  Thanks for recommending whynopadlock.com This showed me it's a CSS, JS, GIF, and JPG still with HTTP.  The markup is using links like this:     <img alt="Academic Analytics" src="Client/Images/HeaderBar160.jpg"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99348/discussion-between-user2169261-and-andy-desrosiers).